# transfer data from textbox to streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader

i'm new with c#
before this i try that streamreader read to end data in textbox.
now...i'm try to move data from textbox to another streamreader line by line
i try this code

String filename = ContentBox.Text;

```
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {

                String fileRow = "";

                while ((fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    String[] fileDataField = fileRow.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\t", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    String ListSplitLineByLine = "";

                    //line = line.Replace("\r\n", " ");
                    //String[] SplitItemLineByLine1 = (line).Split(' ');


                    foreach (string lineByLine in fileDataField)
                    {
                        ListSplitLineByLine += "\r\n" + lineByLine;
                    }

                    txtCaseInputs.Text = ListSplitLineByLine.Trim();

                    GenCombItems();

                }
            //Close the StreamReader
            fileReader.Close();
            }

       }
```

it is no error but when i run there is nothing...
is it my coding error?

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, you assign that iteration's result to `txtCaseInputs.Text`, writing "over" the previous iteration's result.

If you want the textbox to contain concatenation of all fields from the file, you should append on each iteration instead of assigning:

```
txtCaseInputs.Text += ListSplitLineByLine.Trim();
```

And don't forget to clear the textbox's contents before starting the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Put a few debug statements in there until you get it working right.

You can always remove them later.

```
public string ZTest(string contentBoxText) {
  string retValue = null;
  string filename = contentBoxText;
  if (File.Exists(filename)) {
    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
      string fileRow;
      while ((fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        string[] fileDataField = fileRow.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\t", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string ListSplitLineByLine = "";
        foreach (string lineByLine in fileDataField) {
          ListSplitLineByLine += "\r\n" + lineByLine;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListSplitLineByLine)) {
          retValue = ListSplitLineByLine.Trim();
          GenCombItems();
        } else {
          MessageBox.Show("No data");
        }
      }
      // Line below is not necessary. Handled by the "using" clause.
      // fileReader.Close();
    }
  } else {
    MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
  }
  return retValue;
}
```

Comment: ContentBox is a textbox that contain data after load.i also try this but still the same..

Comment: The stub I wrote above would be easy for you to test with: `string value = ZTest(ContentBox.Text);` then on the next line `Console.WriteLine(value);` Be sure to set a break point within the `ZTest` method so you can step through the process (using F-10 in Visual Studio).